# How can i change mail Via option using Php mail function

Tags: php, email

I have tried every method of using a contact form with the PHP Mail function to get an email, and while I was able to receive the email, the actual issue I'm having is that I'm getting something that looks like the image below.

[image]

```
if($response->success){
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
  // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
  $message = "<html>
  <head>
  <title> contact form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Glc contact form</p>
  <table style='border: 1px solid;border-collapse: collapse;'>
  <tr style='border: 1px solid'>
  <th style='border: 1px solid'>Name</th>
  <t style='border: 1px solid'h>E-mail</th>
  <th style='border: 1px solid'>Phone</th>
  <th style='border: 1px solid'>Message</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style='border: 1px solid'>
  <td style='border: 1px solid'>$name</td>
  <td style='border: 1px solid'>$email</td>
  <td style='border: 1px solid'>$mobile</td>
  <td style='border: 1px solid'>$message</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  ";
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  // More headers
  $headers .= 'From: <noreply@akiraplc.com>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Cc: nio@aapl.com,per@ak.com' . "\r\n";
 

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: I think that's just the name of the SMTP relay you're sending through.  What problem does it cause?

Comment: _Side note:_ The tag "phpmailer" refers to a specific third party PHP library named "phpmailer" (and not the general `mail()`-function).

Comment: how can I remove that?  I don't want to see that via  when i receive mail.I had used PHP mailer .Smtp folders are there in my root folder.I that something that causes the issue?

Comment: This is a security feature, so that you can't fool the recipients into thinking the mail came from somewhere, it actually didn't. Your server needs to be set up properly to _allow_ sending mails under the name of `noreply@akiraplc.com` - if you are hosting that domain on that same server, go talk to your server admin.